# Counterexample to primitive element theorem

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and let $\alpha,\beta$ be algebraically independent over $k$. Prove the following:

(a) $k(\alpha,\beta)$ has degree $p^2$ over $k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$.

(b) There exists  infinitely many extensions between $k(\alpha,\beta)$ and $k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$.

**Remark:** This problem appeared couple of times in MSE but anyway let me ask the following questions because they are quite subtle and I did not find these moment in previous topics. So please do not duplicate this topic!

**Proof:**
(a) Consider an extension $k(\alpha,\beta^p)$ of $k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$. We'll show that $[k(\alpha,\beta^p):k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)]=p$. Let's take polynomial $p(X)=X^p-\alpha^p\in k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)[X]$ then we see that $p(X)=(X-\alpha)^p$ and $\alpha$ its root. So let $g(X)=\text{Irr}(\alpha,k(\alpha^p,\beta^p),X)$ - irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ over $k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$.

Then $g(X)\mid (X-\alpha)^p$ so $g(X)=(X-\alpha)^i$ with $1\leq i \leq p$.

Suppose that $1\leq i <p$ and we know that $g(X)=(X-\alpha)^i\in k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)[X]$  then constant term $\alpha^i\in k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$ but $\text{gcd}(i,p)=1$ then $\exists \lambda,\mu$ such that $\lambda i+\mu p=1$ and after easy manipulations we get that $\alpha \in k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$.

Thus $\alpha=P(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$ for some $P(x,y)\in k(x,y)$, i.e. $P(x,y)$ could be rational function.
Therefore, $(\alpha,\beta)$ is a root of equation $P(x^p,y^p)-x=0$ where $P(x,y)=\dfrac{A(x,y)}{B(x,y)}$. Finally, $(\alpha,\beta)$ is a root of equation $A(x^p,y^p)-xB(x^p,y^p)=0$. But I guess this is contradiction since $\alpha,\beta$ are algebraically independent and $A(x^p,y^p)-xB(x^p,y^p)$ is a non-zero polynomial (*can anyone explain it? I was not able to understand it. Why this polynomial is non-zero?*).

This contradiction shows that $g(X)=(X-\alpha)^p$ and eventually $[k(\alpha,\beta^p):k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)]=p$.

The same reasoning I guess can be applied to $k(\alpha,\beta)$ over $k(\alpha,\beta^p)$ and this degree is also $p$. Using tower's theorem it gives us that the total degree is $p^2$.

(b) Let's show that there are infinitely many intermediate fields between $k(\alpha,\beta)$ and $k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$.

Let $L=k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$ and $E=L(\alpha,\beta)=k(\alpha,\beta)$. For any $\lambda \in L$ consider intermediate field $L(\alpha+\lambda\beta)$.

There is one key moment: if $L$ is **infinite** then we can show that for any $\lambda\neq \mu$ we have $L(\alpha+\lambda\beta)\neq L(\alpha+\mu\beta)$. It's not so difficult. Indeed, if they are equal then we can show that $L(\alpha,\beta)=L(\alpha+\lambda\beta)$ and $p^2=[L(\alpha+\lambda\beta):L]\leq p$ which is contradiction.

**Question:** But what if $L$ is finite field? Note that in our case $\alpha, \beta$ are not indeterminates. They are just some fixed algebraically independent element over $k$.

I have thought on this many hours but did not come up with something good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what algebraic independence means; because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraically independent over $k$:

1. It follows that $\alpha$ is transcendental over $k(\beta)$ and $\beta$ is transcendental over $k(\alpha)$.
2. In particular $\alpha$ is transcendental over $k(\beta^p)$ and $\beta$ is transcendental over $k(\alpha^p)$.
3. In particular $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both transcendental over $k$.

It follows immediately that $L:=k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$ is an infinite field, solving your second question.

For your first question, I haven't (yet) been able to untangle everything after your sentence

> ...and after easy manipulations we get that $\alpha \in k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$.

But because $\alpha$ is transcendental over $k(\beta^p)$, it follows that $\alpha\notin L=k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$, and you are done.

Also, the algebra is slightly simpler when instead of considering the constant term of $(X-\alpha)^i$, you consider the coefficient of $X^{i-1}$, which is $-i\alpha$. If $p\nmid i$ then $-i$ is a unit in $k$, so if $(X-\alpha)^i\in L[X]$ then also $-i\alpha\in L$ and hence $\alpha\in L$, leading to a contradiction in the same way as above. This shows that $g(X)=(X-\alpha)^p$.

Comment: 1) Could you give more details why $k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$ is an infinite field? I did not even understand why they are both transcendental over $k$.

Comment: I have reordered my thoughts and my answer a bit. I hope it is clearer. If not; I am curious to know what your definition of an algebraically independent set is.

Comment: I have done in the following way (please correct me If I am wrong): since $\alpha$ is transcendental over $k(\beta^p)$ then $\alpha^p$ is also transcendental over $k(\beta^p)$. Suppose the field $k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$ is finite field then $k(\beta^p)$ is also finite. The I guess this extension is also finite. Being finite it should be algebraic. Hence $\alpha^p$ is also algebraic over $k(\beta^p)$ which is contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: The situation is much simpler, at least if we are using the same definitions: For an extension of fields $K\subset L$ an element $\gamma\in L$ is *transcendental over $K$* if and only if the map
$$K[X]\ \longrightarrow\ K[\gamma]:\ f\ \longmapsto\ f(\gamma),$$
is injective. Similarly, elements $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n\in L$ are *algebraically independent* if and only if
$$K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]\ \longrightarrow\ K[\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n]:\ f\ \longmapsto\ f(\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n),$$
is injective. From this, my 3 claims above follow immediately.

Comment: But for the particular claim you are trying to prove; indeed if $k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$ is finite then it is a finite extension of $k(\beta^p)$, and hence algebraic. This implies that $\alpha^p$ is algebraic over $k(\beta^p)$, a contradiction.

Comment: One more question: you said that if $\alpha$ is transcendental over $k(\beta^p)$ it follows that $\alpha \notin k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$. It's not so obvious. But when I trying to prove it I am using the same technique which I've used in my initial post. Indeed, if $\alpha \in k(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$ then $\alpha=p(\alpha^p,\beta^p)/q(\alpha^p,\beta^p)$ and hence $\alpha q(\alpha^p,\beta^p)-p(\alpha^p,\beta^p)=0$. And we have to show that this polynomial, i.e. $xq(x^p,y^p)-p(x^p,y^p)$ is not zero, right?

Comment: That is one way to go about it, and that polynomial is clearly nonzero because $$\deg p(x^p,y^p)\equiv\deg q(x^p,y^p)\equiv0\pmod{p},$$
so $\deg xq(x^p,y^p)\neq\deg p(x^p,y^p)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such brilliant answer! Your answers are always helpful!